# Ubuntu on small partition not booting due to lack of free space on partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I mistakenly installed Ubuntu on a small partition of 14 GB. I've been using it since until I get around to installing it on another partition. I've been regularly using Bleachbit to free up free space.

Now it has stopped booting due to lack of free space. Can I use Bleachbit or similar software, or terminal commands, from an Ubuntu live USB drive to free up disk space? Could I use the "Drop to root shell prompt" from the Ubuntu Recovery Menu?

During the Ubuntu Recovery Menu Clean process "Try to make free space" , errors appear like this one:

Trying to find packages you don't need (apt-get autoremove), please review carefully.

Reading package lists. . .  error!

E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)

Comment: How do you know it doesn't boot due to lack of free space? Any error message saying that? What happens exactly?